# Prove that we can draw a line that contains $N,X,D$.

Tags: geometry

We draw the Incircle of triangle $ABC$ that is tangent to $AB,BC$ at points $N,M$.We pass the line $l$ from the point $I$(Center of the incircle).Then we draw a perpendicular from $C,A$ to that line that intersect that line at $Y,X$.If $MY$ intersects the incircle at $D$ Prove that we can draw a line that contains $N,X,D$.

It seems that we should connect both $N,D$ to $X$ and the continue with angles because we have two right angles and can have more using tangents and we are able to use cyclic quadrilaterals.But I can't get anything using that.

Comment: Is $l$ *any* line passing through $I$, or is some description missing?

Comment: @MatthewConroy It is a random line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides M and N, let K be the third contact point of the in-circle to the line AC. Then, BMIN, ANIK and CMIK are cyclic.

[image]

In addition, AXIK is also cyclic. Thus, A, N, X, I, and K are points on the same (green) circle. Then, $\alpha = \alpha_2 =\alpha_1 =\alpha’$.

Similarly, C, M, I, K, and Y are con-cyclic points on the (blue) circle. Then, $\beta’ = \beta’’$.

Note that, by “angle in alternate segment”, $\beta = \beta’’$. Therefore, $\beta =\beta' = \beta''$.

Note also that $\angle 1 = \angle 2 = \theta + \beta = \theta + \beta’ = \angle DKY$. This means the line $\lambda$ is the perpendicular bisector of KD. Therefore, $\omega = \alpha’ = \alpha$.

Required result follows.

Comment: Can you upload the picture another where?My computer can't open pictures on SE sites.

Comment: @TahaAkbari Try https://postimg.org/image/45u1xf51h/.

Comment: again doesn't work can you email it?

Comment: taakda22@gmail.com

Comment: @TahaAkbari image sent.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$$\angle NAI=\angle NXI=\alpha\ , \ \angle MCI=\angle MYI=\beta$$

$$\angle NDM=\angle NKN=\alpha+\beta \Rightarrow N,X,D \rightarrow collinear$$

Comment: 1) I guess the con-cyclicies of (ANIXK) and (CMIKY) are assumed. 2) $\angle NKI = \alpha$ too and similarly $\angle MKI = \beta$. 3) $\angle NKN$ should be $\angle NKM$ instead.

Comment: where is $K$???

Comment: Can you upload the picture another where?My computer can't open pictures on SE sites.

Comment: @TahaAkbari http://savepic.net/9818539.png

Comment: OMG.What was the motivation?

Comment: $\angle NDM$ will equal to $\angle NKN (M)$, but is X part of ND?